# Swapping key phrases in URL, Title and H1 tag

Tags: seo, keywords

I was wondering if swapping key phrases would still work in URL, Titlte and H1 tags

For example:

```
Car Sales Melbourne
Sales Car Melbourne

carsalesmelbourne.com.au
salescarmelbourne.com.au
```

So the second key phrase would you be able to get similar effect with correct key phrase or if location is different, would this not work at all?

Comment: Could you please explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @MarcoDemaio what I mean by this is that if the keywords are switched around on different position, would it have same effect as Exact Match Domain names? So carsalesmelbourne with salescarmelbourne

Answer (score 3):

EMD (exact match domains) are not as good as they used to be since Google clamped down on people opting to use keyword rich domains over well thought up business name and brands. Google wants individuals and businesses to come up with good branding, business names and just good sounding websites.

*You should opt to use something like:*

```
businessname.com/cars-for-sale-in-melbourne
```

**A couple of links to read about the Google EMD Update**

- http://www.seomoz.org/blog/googles-emd-algo-update-early-data
- http://www.searchenginejournal.com/your-guide-to-googles-emd-algorithm-update/49915/

**Early Reports**

While some EMDS websites have been hit harder than overs some still have the same rankings and I would imagine this is because of site age, authority, back links. Like Google panda and penguin updates we never know what to expect to see next. And because of this I imagine we will receive many more EMD updates.

**I'm not implying you can't rank EMD's**

This isn't to say you can't rank a EMD but the keywords in them no longer hold as much weight as they used to.. in this effect your better of just using a well thought out business/brand name while using rich keywords in the URL's additionally many believe that its actually easier to rank deep links rather than the route domain in anycase because its more natural in terms of backlinking to deeper links with more resourceful information than the front page but this is another debate.

Comment: Excellent references and answer

Comment: I agree with Simon Hayter. Business name / brand and geolocation are important. I helped a church whom had Central-United-Church.org We opted to also get Central-United-Sarnia.org since we are located in Sarnia. Central United Church is everywhere and not unique.